# XPath 2.0: how to select the current node - current() no longer available

Tags: xpath, xpath-2.0

In XPath 1.0 there's a function *current()* that comes in handy when I refer to a node somewhere else in the XML based on the node I'm in at the moment. 
My XML has a structure like this:

```
<root>
    <book>
        <chapter>
            <section>
                <para>
                    <image id="1">1.png</image>
                </para>
            </section>
        </chapter>
    </book>
    <objects>
        <Object>
            <ID>1</ID>
        </Object>
    </objects>
</root>
```

When I process the *para* nodes in *book*, I sometimes use XPath expressions like this one to look up information in the objects nodes:

```
Object[ID=current()/descendant::image[1]/@id]
```

When I switch my parser to XPath 2.0, this expression gives an error (function current is not available).

I've done some searching, but haven't been able to find a straight replacement for this function. Is there one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `current()` function is defined in XSLT, not in XPath. It's available in XPath expressions within XSLT 1.0, 2.0, and 3.0 stylesheets, but it's not available in free-standing XPath (in any version, except perhaps as a non-conformant extension).

In XPath 2.0 there's a workaround using variables:

```
Object[ID=current()/descendant::image[1]/@id]
```

becomes

```
for $x in descendant::image[1]/@id return Object[ID=$x]
```

Comment: I'm using the XPath/XQuery builder in Oxygen 15.0. When I set that to use XPath 1.0, it accepts the query, when I set it to use XPath 2.0 the error appears. I'll do some more tests.

Comment: That's then an Oxygen issue.

Comment: @Hobbes - I'm also able to reproduce that behavior in oXygen 16.1. Maybe try searching/posting the [oXygen forum](https://www.oxygenxml.com/forum/).

Answer (score 3):

The `current()` function is only available in XSLT (all versions). It's not available in XPath (any version).

See the [`current()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#function-current) function description in the "[Additional Functions](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#add-func)" section of the spec.